# JQuery AJAX calling local update script fails in Safari, works in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

Making an AJAX call on a local script to update dbase using POST. Error reporting is not giving me much to go on.  Works in IE, Chrome and FF, but not Safari 6.  Other JQuery features are working in Safari, and Firebug DOM tab is showing JQuery has.  Here is the AJAX code block.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updatead3.php",
    data: {pos_data: dd_elm},   //index array created earlier
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
}).done (function(data) {
    if(console && console.log) {
       console.log("AJAX success: " + data);
    }
}).fail(function(obj,status,error) {
     alert("AJAX Error:" + obj.error);
});

alert("Changes were saved!");
location.reload();
)};
)}:
```

Under the Firebug Scripts tab > Inspect jquery-1.9.1.js menu option, "Access to restricted URI denied" is being displayed.  But if this were a cross domain issue, I wouldn't expect any JQuery functionality.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are there any issues in the Safari Javascript console?

Comment: Hi No, no javascript errors in console.

Comment: the page displays a group of image and text elements,  their position is defined in a database.  The reload is to allow the process to get the updated values for the new element positions.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase it: how do you expect AJAX to succeed before the browser reloads the page? It's not contained in either `done` or `fail` or `complete` part - it just hangs out there.

Comment: @raina77ow hmm, I see your point.  I'll move the reload() to the end of the script and see.

Comment: @raina77ow, nope, that caused a infinite loop of just reloading the page.  The AJAX call should be complete before the alert("changes were saved").

Comment: Placing the code directly under `$.ajax()` doesn't make it run _after_ AJAX call is complete. Placing the code in `$.ajax().always(function(){})` does, however. I actually expected you to use the latter. )

Comment: @raina77ow, THAT DID IT.  If you add that as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with `$.ajax` (or any asynchronous code for that matter), one should always remember: *'below'* doesn't mean *'after'*.

To make some code executed right after `$.ajax()` call is resolved, successfully or not, it's not enough just to write it under `$.ajax` - actually, unless it introduces a waiting block (like `alert` does), its code will always be executed *before* any ajax callback has a chance to work.

Instead you should use methods provided by the `Promise` interface (and `jqXHR` object, returned by `$.ajax`):

- [**.done()**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), which is fired when AJAX call is resolved successfully
- [**.fail()**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/), which is fired when AJAX call is resolved with an error
- [**.always()**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/), which is fired when AJAX call is resolved anyway (and all the callbacks specified in `.done`/`.fail` methods have been completed too).

In this particular case you trigger the page's reload while the AJAX call is still processed. That's confusing for some browsers, first, and actually in most cases prevents you from correctly processing the results of AJAX.

What should be done instead is placing the code into `$.ajax().always()` callback:

```
$.ajax({ some: 'settings'})
 .done(function() { console.log('SUCCESS :)'); })
 .fail(function() { console.log('FAIL :('); })
 .always(function() { console.log('Doh, I\'m fired anyway'); });
```